# Windows subprocess with arguments

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I need to run `pdb2mdb.exe` utility, and pass DLL file as argument.

After long googling, and playing with various `call/Popen` - I still can't find solution...

Here is last code:

```
def pdb2mdb(logger, modsrcdll):


    os.chdir("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\MonoBleedingEdge\\lib\\mono\\4.0\\")
    subprocess.call("pdb2mdb.exe %s" % modsrcdll)
```

But - this way pdb2mdb.exe don't want accept argument, and prints it's help:

```
Copy file d:\***.dll to C:\cloudlibrary\data
Copy file D:\***.dll.xml to C:\cloudlibrary\data
PDP FOUND
pdbexe found
Mono pdb to mdb debug symbol store converter
Usage: pdb2mdb assembly
```

Without `os.chdir()` - it can't parse `C:\\Program Files (x86)` at all...

I have used `subprocess.call()` earlier under Linux, and never had such problems, for example:

`subprocess.call('ls -l %s | grep -v total' % self.path, shell=True)`

Comment: Paths with embedded space characters have to be quoted with `"`. i.e. `subprocess.call('pdb2mdb.exe "%s"' % modsrcdll)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

```
p = subprocess.Popen("pdb2mdb.exe modsrcdll", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
print err
```

**Example**: The code below will open `notepad.exe` from `C:\\Windows\\System32` and give the file `test.txt`as an argument. The same might work for your `.dll`

```
import subprocess

    def myFunc():   
        p = subprocess.Popen("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe c:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test.txt", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = p.communicate()
        print out
        print err

    myFunc()
```